# Custom correlation function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a custom function for pearson's correlation coefficient with this code in matlab 2010

```
function [p] = customcorr(o)
x := a
y := b
x_mean := mean(a)
y_mean := mean(b)
x_std := std(a)
y_std := std(b)
n := length(o)
r := (1/(n-1))*((x-x_mean)*(y-y_mean))/(x_std*y_std)
end
```

But i get an error when trying to execute it

```
Error in ==> customcorr at 2
x := a
```

Anybody might know what the problem is? Thank you

Comment: The problem is that `:=` is not Matlab syntax! It's just `=`. Also in future please include the actual error message. BTW you are also going to get errors later in your `r=...` line because you are using matrix operators instead of element-wise operators. You'll need to change all your `*`s to `.*`s and the same for `/` to `./`

Comment: Thank you, that was useful, but now i get this error, which i suppose is because a and b are not defined in the code, they are arrays with 50 elements and i have already loaded data in them in matlab, but I am not sure if they can be defined in the code?
??? Undefined function or variable 'a'.
Error in ==> customcorr at 2
x = a;

Comment: of course you do, because as the error message very clearly states, you have not defined `a` yet! So how can you assign it to anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the correct MATLAB syntax: a "normal" assignment is done by `=`, not by `:=`.

Second, you use `a` and `b` but these are not defined as parameters of the function. Replace the function head by `function p = customcorr(a,b)`.

Third, I am not really sure what `o` should be, I assume it can be replaced by `length(a)` or `length(b)`.

The estimator for an unbiased correlation coefficient is given by

[image: corr]

(from wikipedia)

Thus you need to sum all the `(a-a_mean).*(b-b_mean)` up with `sum`. Note that it is required to write `.*` to get the element-wise multiplication. That way you subtract the mean from each element of the vectors, then multiply the corresponding `a`'s and `b`'s and sum up the results of these multiplications.

Together this is

```
function p = customcorr(a,b)
    a_mean = mean(a);
    b_mean = mean(b);
    a_std = std(a);
    b_std = std(b);
    n = length(a);
    p = (1/(n-1)) * sum((a-a_mean).*(b-b_mean)) / (a_std*b_std);
end
```

What MATLAB does in their `corr` function (besides many other interesting things) is, they check the number of arguments (`nargin` variable) to see if `a` and `b` were supplied or not. You can do that by adding the following code to the function (at the beginning)

```
if nargin < 2
    b = a;
end
```

Comment: That was so helpful, thank you, its working properly now!
Just as an extra, you know the built-in corr function shows 1 when i use it for a single variable corr(a) or corr(b), but my custom one does not let me use a single element saying 
customcorr(a)
??? Input argument "b" is undefined.

Error in ==> customcorr at 5
y = b;
Do you have any idea how can i make it do? THANKYOU

Comment: I added something to do that. I hope this works for you